# Extract a string when there is a match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to ignore the values after -w2 and extract 'JLC-22 VILA'

```
var item="JLC-522 VUOTILA-w2",

item.replace('-w','')
```

I want to ignore the values after -w2 and extract 'JLC-22 VILA'

The item value is dynamic item values keeps changing like "JLC-22 VILA-w18"
"JBC-12 KULA-w23"

Comment: Try `.replace(/\-w\d+$/, '')` this will work if `w` is always followed by numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Match any characters, while looking ahead for `-w` after the end of the match:

```js
var item="JLC-522 VUOTILA-w2";
const output = item.match(/.+(?=-w)/)[0];
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you will not have `-w` you wanna keep you can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split) function

```js
const item="JLC-522 VUOTILA-w2";

const str = item.split('-w')[0];
console.log(str);
```